# Offset top how to implement this?

Tags: javascript, anchor

I am creating a onepage design. Now I work with a fixed header menu with links that are linked to there sections. I have get some code for get a smooth look.

**Problem**
When I click a menu item, it will go to the correct section, but the section will be on top of the browser screen. Now I want to add a offset of 120px top. How can I do this?

CODE:

```
// When you click on an <a> that has a '#'
$('nav#primary-navwrapper a[href^="#"]').bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
    // Prevent from default action to intitiate
    e.preventDefault();
    // Targets the part of the address that comes after the '#'
    var target = this.hash;
        $target = $(target);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        // The .offset() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element relative to the document.
        // Here we are using it to find the position of the target, which we defined earlier as the section of the address that will come after the '#'
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 500, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});
```

Thank you.
Casper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
'scrollTop': $target.offset().top + 120
```